# Format Date from 25th March 2014 to digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, format

does any one know how i can convert a date from 25th March 2014 to digits so its like 20140325 but stuck at the moment cant find any answers..

thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var myDate = new Date("March 25 2014");
document.write(myDate.getFullYear()+""+("0" + (myDate.getMonth()+1)).substr(-2) + "" + myDate.getDate());
```

[see here demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/6rx82/)

Comment: You could use .toString() on each value. It's a little clearer than adding empty strings and provides the same result.

Comment: @SamR actually tostring is not necessary only concatenation `+` is required, it looks me more clear [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/6rx82/1/)

Comment: Ah, the substr for padding the month forces the numbers to strings. Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
var months = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12'];

var getMonthNow=months[CurrentDate.getMonth()];
```

And display the getMonthNow where ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function formatDate(d) {   
  return d.getFullYear()+ ("0"+(d.getMonth()+1)).substr(-2)+ d.getDate();
}

var date =  new Date()    // date = Tue Mar 25 2014 15:40:33 

formatDate(date);         // "20140325"
```